# Printing from one application intermittantly will lock up print queue for one printer. Is there a way to work around this?

Tags: windows, printing, printer

It's only with one application to one printer. Using a different printer is, unfortunately, out of the question.

I can't expect the users to manually clear the print queue each time it occurs. I've tried replacing the drivers at least four times now and nothing has worked consistently. At this point I'm considering finding some sort of intermediary application that will print it to a PDF then print the PDF on the printer, but I'm not sure such an application exists. If anyone knows of one or can think of some other solution, I would love to hear it.

To clarify, the application is a proprietary ebook reader for a specific set of veterinary info handouts. It appears to corrupt the file name when sending to the printer to have random symbols in the path. It's a particularly annoying issue because it's intermittent. I'll be able to get it to work until it stops working an hour later and breaks it until I address it again. I've tried every version of the drivers for this printer that I could find online; including PCL6, PS, etc.

Comment: i think finding a software print server is the best way to go

Comment: What's the problem application, and does it consistently happen with all docs sent from that application?  I've fixed a similar issue by adjusting the default margins on a misbehaving app to fit well inside the printer's real margins.  The app could be sending the wrong paper size too.

Comment: "I've tried replacing the drivers at least four times now and nothing has worked consistently."  What was different about the various drivers you tried?  Often if PCL6 locks up, PCL5 or PS will work fine, so please edit your question and add details.

Comment: @arthurkamande Do you happen know of any specific ones that work well?

Comment: You could probably put some automation around this to auto correct the issue when it occurs. You could run an AutoIT script for example once a minute and if there's a windows with the title (or some other meta data) that's up, you then execute some action(s). Such as close the windows, stop the print spooler, delete the files from the spooled printer files, restart the print spool service again, and then restart the eBook process again or whatever and sit there and check again every one minute or something. Or yes, dump all to PDF and then the end-users open from network share, URL link, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that behavior before with "special" ebook readers.
(In my case service/workshop manuals for cars.)

The reader software does it intentionally as a form of copy-right protection.
They don't want you to print all the documents in bulk and then photocopy the lot.
They rather sell you more licenses to use the software on multiple computers.

So every X printouts they intentionally send bad data to the Windows printer-interface. This causes the error to happen in the Windows printer-interface itself, even before Windows can hand over the document to the actual printer-driver.

This means that changing drivers/printers/use a network printer/pdf printer doesn't help.
The other "printer" is still a Windows printer and will be subject to the same problem. Any print-job still goes through the regular Windows printer-interface, where the "illegal filename" issue is causing the problem.

So basically you will have to live with this.

Comment: Talk about "annoyware"...

Comment: While that sounds like it could potentially be the issue, printing to the other office printer doesn't seem to have the problem and the printer we replaced with this one didn't seem to have the problem.

I will be doing testing to see if this is the case.

Comment: @Austin You say the "filename" that is send to the printer is bad causing the issue. That filename is generated by the reader software. It shouldn't make any difference which printer you use as the printer(driver) has nothing to do with that. They would all suffer the same issue. Or something else is going on which you didn't notice happening.